# How to write percent (%) symbol to txt using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

i want to create 1_colecting_table.sql file using batch programing. My batch script like this

```
echo select 'DROP ' ^|^|object_type ^|^|' '^|^|object_name^|^|';' from user_objects > sql\1_colecting_table.sql 
echo where object_name NOT LIKE '%613%'; >> sql\1_colecting_table.sql
```

result (1_colecting_table.sql )

```
select 'DROP ' ||object_type ||' '||object_name||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;' from user_objects 
where object_name NOT LIKE '13';
```

why line `"...where object_name NOT LIKE '13'..."` not like this `"...where object_name NOT LIKE '%613%'..."`  ? how to write `%` symbol?

Comment: :) solved by me..i have change line `echo where object_name NOT LIKE '%613%'; >> sql\1_colecting_table.sql` become `echo where object_name NOT LIKE '%%613%%'; >> sql\1_colecting_table.sql`. added double `%` symbol. i'am so sorry and thank'a All

Comment: @FoggyDay : Yes. work 100% :) . thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

To write a percentage symbol (to file or the screen) in batch you can do something like this:

```
@echo ^%613^% > SomeTextFile.txt
```